# Command to count the characters present in the variable

Tags: linux

I am trying to count the number of characters present in the variable. I used the below shell command. But I am getting error - command not found in line 4

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in one; do
n = $i | wc -c
echo $n
done
```

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

In bash you can just write `${#string}`, which will return the length of the variable `string`, i.e. the number of characters in it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in one; do
n=$(echo $i | wc -c)
echo $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignments in bash cannot have a space before the equals sign. In addition, you want to capture the output of the command you run and assign that to `$n`, rather than that statement which would probably just assign `$i` to `$n`.

Use the following instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in one; do
n=`$i | wc -c`
echo $n
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as that:

```
str="abcdef"; wc -c <<< "$str"
7
```

But mind you that end of line counts as a character:

```
str="abcdef";  cat -A <<< "$str"
abcdef$
```

If you need to remove it:

```
str="abcdef"; tr -d '\n' <<< "$str" |  wc -c
6
```